# Magical Record iCloud updating core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm not sure how to get notified of iCloud changes using Magical Record, or even how to fetch them. The only time it updates with iCloud is when I call save, and it seems inefficient to do so when i don't actually have changes.

Answer (score 0):

I see in a source code `kMagicalRecordPSCDidCompleteiCloudSetupNotification`.

Have you tried to subscribe to it?

Answer (score 0):

Where persistent store associated with iCloud changes, it post `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification`. You should subscribe for this notifications and update UI when it thrown.
Changes can be fetched as usual, using `MR_find...` methods or using fetch controllers `MR_fetch...`